How can I GET all the webform submissions via REST?
I am able to retrieve individual records but not all.
How can I GET all the webform submissions in POSTMAN?

I think that with the webform_rest module, you cannot yet get a list of submissions for a form. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/3133989. You can try the patch on that issue, or, there is another answer with a different approach.

You may go with json api, calling the relative end points will respect the permission for each webform. You need the following module or manipulate the data in the front end https://www.drupal.org/project/json_api_webform_submissions
